# What is the right way to do validation in RactiveJS app

Tags: validation, ractivejs

I have several inputs and a button. I want to do something on button click, but before I need to validate inputed data. If data is incorrect, app should highlight inputs and show a message.
What is "canonical" way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: *there's no convention*.

You can roll with *any validation library you choose*, so as long as you can hook it up, show invalid input errors, as well as prevent the form from submitting if the form is invalid.